# Can I reinstall Windows on a Laptop after a Wipe?

Tags: windows-7, linux, reinstall, wipe

I want to run single-boot Linux on my ThinkPad x220, but I want to retain the option of going back to Windows later. There is a sticker with the product key (Windows 7 Pro) on the bottom of the laptop.

**Will this be enough to re-install?**

Comment: yes but if you think you are not that expert then put a new hard drive in and install windows on that to make sure you can do it no surprises (rather than wiping). You may need to locate drivers online for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, you just need to repartition/reformat your disk(s) with ntfs filesystem because linux uses different fs (ext2, ext3...). Your windows license can be used any time on that hardware.